# php want to send bbc

Tags: php, forms, email

```
<?php

define( 'PAYPAL_ID' , '' ); // Put donation ID here to disable the bottom backlink

define( 'PHPFMG_TO' , 'email1@gmail.com');

define( 'PHPFMG_REDIRECT', '' ); 

define( 'PHPFMG_ID' , '20140311-58f9' ); 
define( 'PHPFMG_ROOT_DIR' , dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'PHPFMG_SAVE_FILE' , PHPFMG_ROOT_DIR . '/form-data-log.php' ); // save submitted data to this file
define( 'PHPFMG_EMAILS_LOGFILE' , PHPFMG_ROOT_DIR . '/email-traffics-log.php' ); // log email traffics to this file
if( !defined('PHPFMG_ADMIN_URL') ) define( 'PHPFMG_ADMIN_URL' , 'admin.php' ); // might be defined already by wordpress form loader plugin

define( 'PHPFMG_SAVE_ATTACHMENTS' , '' );
define( 'PHPFMG_SAVE_ATTACHMENTS_DIR' , PHPFMG_ROOT_DIR . '/uploaded/' );
...
```

hy, i want to add a bbc to my form mailer, and can't figure out where to put the new code or what to change, basically i'm a complete noob when it comes to php, thanks for the solution in front. Cheers jenny!

Comment: what is bbc in this context? the provided "code" seems not related to the question.

Comment: i believe it is bcc( blind carbon copy ) not bbc

Comment: define( 'PHPFMG_TO' , 'email1@gmail.com');

Comment: yeah pardon for that i ment blind carbon copy

Answer (score 0):

`define('PHPFMG_BCC','youraddress@domain.com');`